# ros nao publish bottom camera images

Tags: ros, naoqi, camera, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone

I am wanting to watch the image projected by NAO from its bottom camera. with Rqt I am changing the camera manually from TOP to Bottom (Since currently I don't know how to do that in ROS), however when I run my code I, the window showing the image tries to be open and then it closes again without showing anything. After that I just receive this message.

[ INFO] [1431005812.789945492]: Waiting for action server to start.
[ INFO] [1431005814.826991562]: Action finished: SUCCEEDED
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Now, when I keep the TOP camera and I run my program, the image is shown.

I am publishing camera images using

rosrun naoqi_sensors cameras

Could you please tell me what's the thing I am doing wrong? What's the thing I should change? Is there needed a new camera publisher I need to try?

If you want me to send the code I can also load it here, but I don't think it's because of that

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208775/ros-nao-publish-bottom-camera-images/) by [Diego](https://answers.ros.org/users/21507/diego/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I already solved it. It was just that I left the camera working in choreographe and because of this it could not access well. Thanks anyway.

---

Originally posted by [Diego](https://answers.ros.org/users/21507/diego/) with karma: 46 on 2015-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0